# Variance Dependent on Past Observations: What can be said about convergence?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

everyone. I have only recently embarked on a journey through measure theoretic probability and was pondering the following question:

Consider a process with $$X_n|X_{n-1} \sim N(0, X_{n-1}^2).$$ Define $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ and $T_n = X_1^2 + X_2^2 + \cdots + X_n^2.$ Do $\frac{S_n}{n}$ and $\frac{T_n}{n}$ converge almost surely to $0$? If so, why? From my simulations it seems that both certainly converge to 0, though I can't seem to justify why.

Comment: I suppose you start with $X_1 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0; 1).$ Is this correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: It seems you have $S_n = Z_1 + Z_1 Z_2 + \ldots + Z_1 \cdots Z_n,$ all the $Z_i$ are independent standard normals (so $X_i = Z_1 \cdots Z_i$). Under these circumstances, $S_n/n \to 0$ in $\mathscr{L}^2.$ On the other hand, $T_n$ has expected value $n,$ so there is no convergence of $T_n \to 0$ in $\mathscr{L}^2.$ At any rate, this representation of $S_n$ may be worth using. I suspect you will need to adapt the proof of Kolmogorov inequality and then that of the SLLN to suit your needs.

Comment: Interesting, I would never have thought to represent the $X_i$ in that way. However, that's not the only possible representation of the $X_i$ that yields the required distribution, right? So we have convergence if the process is indeed as you have defined, but does the convergence of the process you have defined imply convergence for all other representations of the process?

Comment: It really depends what you mean with $X_n \mid X_{n-1} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0; X_{n-1}^2).$ I interpreted this as "knowing $X_{n-1},$ $X_n$ is, independently of everything else, a normal random variable with zero mean and standard deviation $|X_{n-1}|.$" If this is what you also meant, then no, my representation is a theorem that can be proved. Otherwise, the problem my be undetermined (in such cases you'd be looking for stochastic convergences in lieu of a.s., such as convergence in some mean sense, in measure or weakly).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This was very instructive and useful for me.